# Who organized the Haftarot and when?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, history, haftarah, tractate-megillah

If I'm not mistaken, Masechet Megillah mentions a few haftarot, I think, mainly for Yom Tov. I don't recall much mentioned about the weekly Shabbat haftarot.

In most Chumashim, I noticed that there are frequently different haftarot for Sephardim and Ashkenazim. Sometimes, these differences include Polish, Italian, and some other minhagim.

Who organized which haftarot should be said each week as well as for "special" occasions (e.g. Shabbat Rosh Hodesh, the 4 parshiot, etc.) and when where these compiled?

Comment: There's no reason to think it was a specific person who did it. Probably they predate recorded organizers. It's like who split the Torah into Parshas.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah

Comment: Luke 4:16–21 (written in the first century CE) is the earliest ostensible reference to the haftarah. The pericope describes Jesus reading Isaiah 61:1–2 on Shabbat in a synagogue.